# Characteristic functions of Poisson and normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions

Basically the question is in two parts:

$1.)$Finding the characteristic of $P{(\lambda)}$, and it is given, I just do not know how to get the sum that they got in the very last step in this expression(last equality is unclear):
$$f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}e^{itj}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!}e^\lambda=e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$$

$2.)$Finding the characteristic function of $N(0,1)$ and the last equality in the expression is unclear.

$$
f_X(t) = \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{itx}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx
       = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R}\cos(tx)e^{-x^2/2}dx
$$

(I thought the reason for this is that the product of a even and odd function in an integral is $0$ but that's just probably my wishful thinking doing )

and the very last part that is unclear is that is says after differentiating this last line we get:
$$
f_{X}'(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}
            \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (-x)\sin (tx)e^{-x^2/2}dx
$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your expression gives
$$
\begin{split}
f(t) &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{itj} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}e^\lambda \\
     &= e^\lambda \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\left(e^{it} \lambda\right)^j}{j!} \\
     &= e^\lambda e^{\lambda e^{it}} \\
     &= e^{\lambda(e^{it}+1)}
\end{split}
$$

You likely meant $e^{-\lambda}$ not $e^\lambda$:
$$
\begin{split}
f(t) &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{itj} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda} \\
     &= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\left(e^{it} \lambda\right)^j}{j!} \\
     &= e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda e^{it}} \\
     &= e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}
\end{split}
$$

As for (2), recall Euler's formula,
$$
e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x), \quad i = \sqrt{-1}
$$

Comment: that was very quick, and even more impressive!

Comment: @BozoVulicevic ;-) thanks

Comment: One question only: the second last equality in finding the sum, how do you know the sum is equal to that function of $e$? Could you abbreviate on such?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Taylor series: $$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: Im going to add one more line to my question in relation to integration, I hope you can check that out too, I would me immensely grateful.

Comment: edited. :) ${}{}{}$

Comment: @BozoVulicevic for (3),. just exchange the order of deriv and integral: $$\frac{d}{dt} \left[ \int f(t,x) dx \right] = \int \frac{d}{dx} \left[ f(t,x) \right] dx$$
under some nice conditions